# How to handle multiple models using PaperClip?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, activeadmin

I am building an app built on top of Active Admin. The idea is to have a backend I can control and update/edit using a CMS like interface. From there, I am building an API on the data I am controlling in Active Admin. Using that API, I am displaying it with Angular.js on the front end.

The problem I am running into, is using Paperclip. Pictures/images are very important to this project, and being able to access the data from paperclip is equally important.

The current problem is when I am in the Admin section of the site. I have 2 main sections set up, `Project` and `Member`. I have my various fields set up, and everything worked fine, and I was able to generate an API. Then I added pictures and everything broke. Here is my current set up;

**project.rb** (projects have multiple images)

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images
end
```

**member.rb** (has 1 image)

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image
end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :member
belongs_to :project

# PaperClip
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "100x100", :medium => "200x200", :large => "300x300" }, 
              :url  => "/path/to/images/url", 
              :path => ":path/to/images"
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type:     ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }

accepts_nested_attributes_for :member, :project
```

end

The current error I am getting is;

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: image)
```

This was from changing something after getting;

```
Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):
```

I have run migrations, changed migrations, messed around with a bunch of other resources, and I still don't know exactly what is causing the problem. It seems like it could be a couple different things and I try to implement those fixes, but it always just leads me to another error or just causes a run-a-round.

Any help would be appreciated. I can post more code if it helps in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true` in your Project and Member class.
And you also have to permit the images in your ActiveAdmin model:

```
permit_params images_attributes: [:id, :image, :_destroy]
```

What's happening when you don't validate the attachment at all?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was able to get it solved by getting rid of **image.rb** and put the paperclip info into the models I need to use. The only problem now, is when I generate an API the pictures show up on the **members.rb** model and not the **project.rb** model. Not quite sure why, but I'll figure it out.